# How to grep '---' in Linux? grep: unrecognized option '---'

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, grep, ubuntu-10.04

I have a newly installed web application. In that there is a drop down where one option is `---`. What I want to do is change that to `All`. So I navigated to application folder and tried the below command.

```
grep -ir '---' .
```

I end up with below error.

```
grep: unrecognized option '---'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Given that I'm using

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:    10.04
Codename:   lucid
```

How to grep '---' in Linux ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This happens because `grep` interprets `---` as an option instead of a text to look for. Instead, use `--`:

```
grep -- "---" your_file
```

This way, you tell `grep` that the rest is not a command line option.

Other options:

- use `grep -e` (see [Kent's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443473/1983854), as I added it when he had already posted it - didn't notice it until now):
- use `awk` (see [anubhava's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443421/1983854)) or `sed`:

  ```
  sed -n '/---/p' file
  ```

`-n` prevents `sed` from printing the lines (its default action). Then `/---` matches those lines containing `---` and `/p` makes them be printed.

Answer (score 11):

use grep's `-e` option, it is the right option for your requirement:

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified
          by POSIX.)
```

> **to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-)**

Comment: For completeness: `egrep` can also be used which is equivalent to `grep -e --color=auto` but is provided as a precompiled binary.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to escape each `-` with a backslash.

```
grep '\-\-\-' your_file
```

Escaping only the first `-` works too:

```
grep '\---' your_file
```

An alternative without quotes:

```
grep \\--- your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use awk:

```
awk '/---/' file
```

Or sed:

```
sed -n '/---/p' file
```