# trying to grep '--string' fails

Tags: grep, special-characters

I'm trying to grep for a string that starts with "--"

for some reason it counted as special character, but even when trying to use -F then grep gives me bad syntax:

[root@pc-01 /]# grep -F `--restore` *.*
-bash: --restore: command not found

any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grep '---' in Linux? grep: unrecognized option '---'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443339/how-to-grep-in-linux-grep-unrecognized-option)

Answer (score 0):

Try following.
grep -F `--` --restore *filename*

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the first `-` :

Without escaping:

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST2 tmp]# echo '--aa --bb --cc' | grep -o '--b'
grep: option '--b' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--basic-regexp' '--binary' '--byte-offset' '--binary-files' '--before-context'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Escaping:

```
[root@TIAGO-TEST2 tmp]# echo '--aa --bb --cc' | grep -o '\--b'
--b
```