# grep: invalid context length argument

Tags: grep

I want to check if an iptables rule exists (as seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/360094/how-can-i-check-if-an-iptables-rule-already-exists)), but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo iptables-save | grep "-A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags  RST RST -j DROP"
grep:  OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags  RST RST -j DROP: invalid context length argument
```

Perhaps I have to escape some characters?

Comment: `grep` is seeing `-A` as an argument and not the pattern. You need to use `-e "..."`.

Comment: that worked, thank you!

Comment: @EtanReisner If you post that as an answer, Ricky can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I know. I also know that this is something that comes up a lot and I really don't want to have *another* answer for it. I'd love a good duplicate but hadn't found one yet (though I just did).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25443339/258523

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Problem

> grep "-A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags  RST RST -j DROP"

With many shell tools, some arguments can be mistakenly interpreted as flags. Depending on your version of grep, the following will help grep understand that the "flags" aren't really flags, but are part of the expression you're searching for.

For example, consider:

```
$ echo "-Afoo" | grep  "-Afoo"
grep: Invalid argument
```

### Solutions

#### Flags to Demarcate Expressions

1. Use the special `--` flag to indicate that no flags follow.

   ```
   grep -- "-A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags  RST RST -j DROP"
   ```
2. Use the `-e` flag to explicitly identify the quoted text that follows as an expression to search for.

   ```
   grep -e "-A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags  RST RST -j DROP"
   ```

#### Examples of Solutions

This works for me either way with BSD grep. Consider the following examples:

```
$ echo "-Afoo" | grep -- "-Afoo"
-Afoo

$ echo "-Afoo" | grep -e "-Afoo"
-Afoo
```

While the examples are admitedly contrived, they illustrate the problem (and the solution) much more clearly, and can easily be tested even on systems that don't have iptables to use as input text.